# How to log HTTP requests in file in Dropwizard?

Tags: apache-2.4, logging, java, yaml, fedora-31

I'm having issue in my Dropwizard (**version 1.3.8**) app logging HTTP Requests into file. I've followed Dropwizard's [documentation](https://www.dropwizard.io/en/release-1.3.x/manual/configuration.html#file) for configuration of YAML file and my `config.yml` looks like this:

```yaml
logging:
  level: INFO
  loggers:
    com.nikolas.master_thesis: DEBUG

  appenders:
    - type: file
      currentLogFilename: /home/nikola/Documents/DWApp-LOGs/DW-Bookshop_LOG.log
      threshold: ALL
      queueSize: 512
      archive: true
      archivedLogFilenamePattern: /home/nikola/Documents/DWApp-LOGs/DW-Bookshop_LOG-%d.log
      archivedFileCount: 5
      timeZone: UTC
      logFormat: "%-5p [%d{ISO8601,UTC}] %c: %m%n%rEx"
      # logFormat: "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-agent}i\"" combined
#      logFormat: “%h %l %u %t “%r“ %s %b “%{Referer}i“ “%{User-Agent}i““ combined
#      logFormat: '%h %l %u %t '%r' %\\>s %b '%{Referer}i' '%{User-Agent}i''
#      logFormat: "%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %com.nikolas.master_thesis.examples.`config-kt`.logger{36} - %msg%n"
#      logFormat: “%h %l %u %t “%r“ %s %b “%{Referer}i“ “%{User-Agent}i““
#      logFormat: "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %s %O \"%{Referer}i\""
#      logFormat: “%h %l %u %t “%r“ %\\>s %b “%{Referer}i“ “%{User-Agent}i““
#      logFormat: "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" \"%>s\" %O \"%{Referer}i\""
#      logFormat: "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
#      logFormat: combined
#      logFormat: "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" /etc/httpd
#      logFormat: “%h %l %u %t “%r” %s %b “%{User-Agent}i””
#      logFormat: "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" /etc/httpd
#      logFormat: "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b"
#        logFormat: "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-agent}i\""
      bufferSize: 8KB
      immediateFlush: true
      # filterFactories:
      #   - type: URI
    
    - type: console
      threshold: ALL
      queueSize: 512
      discardingThreshold: 0
      timeZone: UTC
      target: stdout
      logFormat: "%-5p [%d{ISO8601,UTC}] %c: %m%n%rEx"
```

The thing is that HTTP Request is logged in console like this:

```
192.168.1.5 - - [09/Aug/2020:10:08:05 +0000] "GET /api/orders HTTP/1.1" 200 14094 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/4.5.10 (Java/1.8.0_161)" 710
```

...and I want to log it also in file, but it does NOT log it at all! I've tried to use commented `logFormat`s, but I get error for each of those commented `logFormat` values.
E.g. for `logFormat: "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b"` when I run it in terminal (I'm using **RMI parameters to collect JMX samples from remote machine**):

`java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1616 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=1616  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -jar ./target/DW-Bookshop-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar server config.yml`

...I get NumberFormatException:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ">"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.FormatInfo.valueOf(FormatInfo.java:73)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Parser.T(Parser.java:136)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Parser.E(Parser.java:96)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Parser.Eopt(Parser.java:115)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Parser.E(Parser.java:100)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Parser.Eopt(Parser.java:115)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Parser.E(Parser.java:100)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Parser.Eopt(Parser.java:115)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Parser.E(Parser.java:100)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Parser.Eopt(Parser.java:115)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Parser.E(Parser.java:100)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Parser.Eopt(Parser.java:115)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Parser.E(Parser.java:100)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Parser.Eopt(Parser.java:115)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Parser.E(Parser.java:100)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Parser.Eopt(Parser.java:115)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Parser.E(Parser.java:100)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Parser.Eopt(Parser.java:115)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Parser.E(Parser.java:100)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Parser.Eopt(Parser.java:115)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Parser.E(Parser.java:100)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Parser.Eopt(Parser.java:115)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Parser.E(Parser.java:100)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:91)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.PatternLayoutBase.start(PatternLayoutBase.java:83)
    at io.dropwizard.logging.AbstractAppenderFactory.buildLayout(AbstractAppenderFactory.java:243)
    at io.dropwizard.logging.AbstractOutputStreamAppenderFactory.build(AbstractOutputStreamAppenderFactory.java:25)
    at io.dropwizard.logging.DefaultLoggingFactory.configure(DefaultLoggingFactory.java:143)
    at io.dropwizard.cli.ConfiguredCommand.run(ConfiguredCommand.java:83)
    at io.dropwizard.cli.Cli.run(Cli.java:78)
    at io.dropwizard.Application.run(Application.java:93)
    at com.nikolas.master_thesis.DropwizardMasterThesisApplication.main(DropwizardMasterThesisApplication.java:35)
```

BTW, I'm running **Fedora 31 OS** and I'm using **Java 8**.
Any advice/help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Dropwizard has a separate [configuration for request logs](https://www.dropwizard.io/en/release-1.3.x/manual/configuration.html#request-log), have you tried that way?

Comment: Hi Jenneth, didn't run into that part of config and I will definitely try it. Thanks for notice ;)